# Mapping Amazon AWS EC2 AMI images to pricing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Amazon AWS EC2 instances give high level pricing for Linux, RHEL, Windows etc. : https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

When launching an instance you have a choice between many AMI images of different OSes / stacks. How do you know which pricing from the page above maps to which AMI image? I assume RHEL image will map to RHEL price. Is it safe to assume any other flavour, Ubuntu e.g., will just be the core linux price?

Comment: The instance types on that page have nothing to do with AMI type. When you launch an AMI, you pick an instance type to run it on.

Comment: If you launch a Windows or RHEL vm, the hourly rate includes license fees for those OSes, as listed in the above link. However when you launch an ami there's no clear link back to that pricing. Presumably if you pick a RHEL image, you'll pay the RHEL fees, but I'd expect more clarity on that during the launch process.

Comment: Launching an AMI doesn't give any pricing details at all, to my recollection. If you're interested in pricing, you'd be on the pricing pages, which have clear tabs for the different available licensed products.

Answer (score 2):

No, Linux-based machines other than RHEL and SLES might have higher charges, but you need to 'subscribe' to those.

When in doubt, just go to the [Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace) to see the prices that correspond to a particular AMI.